# Get the "user agent" string from a new Google Chrome browser session from bash

Tags: bash, google-chrome, command-line, ubuntu-22.04

I want to get the [User Agent HTTP request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) string from a new Google Chrome browser session (just opened) from bash and put it in a variable.

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
USER_AGENT="$(google-chrome --user-agent)"
echo "$USER_AGENT"
```

Output example:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

If it is not possible to do this with the `google-chrome` command, what is an equivalent workaround?

Comment: Ok, I changed the question, now it should be more explanatory. It took me an hour to make it as understandable as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome in [headless](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/headless-chrome/) mode with the `--repl` command line option evaluates Javascript expressions.  You could try something like the following to get the [user agent string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgent):

```
echo navigator.userAgent | /opt/google/chrome/chrome --headless --repl 2> /dev/null | sed 's/^>>> //' | jq -r .result.value
```

Note: Do run the `chrome` binary (e.g. `/opt/google/chrome/chrome`) directly rather than the `google-chrome` shell script, because it seems that the shell script does not support passing the standard input through.

The `sed` command removes the prompt from the output and the `jq` command extracts the value from the JSON string that Chrome prints.

Note however that the user agent string when running Chrome with the [`--headless`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md) command line flag is not identical to the user agent string when running it regularly.  At least Chrome 105 seems to have "HeadlessChrome" instead of "Chrome".

Comment: With `man google-chrome` and `google-chrome --help` I couldn't find the `--headless` and `--repl` parameters, yet they work. What is the manual where they are reported?

Comment: You can answer to my comment please?

Comment: The documentation about the headless mode that I know of is in [this post on Chrome Developers blog](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/headless-chrome/) and in [this README file](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/headless/README.md) file in the chromium source repository.

Comment: This no longer works in Chrome 113. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative approach which is not specific to Chrome and will work with many other browsers and http clients too.  It involves setting up a HTTP server with netcat and capturing the User-Agent header value:

```
echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n' | nc -q 0 -l localhost 8080 | sed -n '/^User-Agent: /Is/.*: //p' & google-chrome --headless http://localhost:8080 2>/dev/null
```

You could replace the google-chrome invocation at the end with another browser or http client.

Answer (score 1):

Another one based on Jukka Matilainen's answer:

```
USER_AGENT=$(
    while read request; do
        [[ $request =~ ^User-Agent:\ (.*)$ ]] && { echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; break; }
    done < <(nc -q0 -l -p 8080) &
    curl http://localhost:8080  2> /dev/null # change curl to whatever cli browser
)
echo "$USER_AGENT"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_ID="My-Script"
/opt/google/chrome/chrome --headless=new --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="$HOME/.config/google-chrome/${SCRIPT_ID}-TMP/" &>/dev/null &
PID=$!
sleep 0.35
curl --retry-connrefused --retry 10 --retry-delay 1 http://localhost:9222/json/version --silent | jq -r '.["User-Agent"]' | sed s/Headless//
kill -SIGINT $PID
```

For redundancy, in case something is interrupted, could also add the following to clean up:

```
for PID in $(ps auxw | grep "config/google-chrome/${SCRIPT_ID}-TMP" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -SIGINT $PID; done
rm "$HOME/.config/google-chrome/${SCRIPT_ID}-TMP/SingletonLock" 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: This is currently the only working solution. Thanks!