# navigator.userAgent no longer works on /opt/google/chrome/chrome since version 113

Tags: bash, shell, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-22.04

This is the site where I learned the procedure to output the userAgent using bash on Ubuntu 22.04:

[Get the "user agent" string from a new Google Chrome browser session from bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73571131)

and I had the command:

```
echo navigator.userAgent | /opt/google/chrome/chrome --headless --repl | perl -pe 's/^>>> //; s/HeadlessChrome/Chrome/g' | jq -r .result.value
```

Which worked perfectly until the version before Chrome 113, after which it gave only errors:

```
[0531/154816.789187:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[0531/154816.807959:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(393)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[0531/154816.812699:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(128)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
```

Solved thanks to the link:

[How to Supress "Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74905110)

But with this code, even if no more errors appear:

```
echo navigator.userAgent | /opt/google/chrome/chrome --headless=new --repl --remote-allow-origins=* | perl -pe 's/^>>> //; s/HeadlessChrome/Chrome/g' | jq -r .result.value
```

The command shell expects input but I've already given it through the pipe, which apparently didn't work.
How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Any sugggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out.

The new `--headless` mode does not have a `--repl` option and the old one is missing the "Floss manager", so the only option you have to access the User Agent is by setting up a `--remote-debugging-port`, like so:

```bash
$ /opt/google/chrome/chrome --headless=new --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

but now you can't get any data because all the commands need to be executed through websockets, you could use `websocat` or `socat` to do so but the debugging port also allows you to get some information just by accessing some HTTP endpoints.

One of the endpoints is `/json/version` which shows the the `User-Agent` property that you are looking for. Here is a short example:

```bash
$ /opt/google/chrome/chrome --headless=new --remote-debugging-port=9222 &>/dev/null &
$ PID=$! # save the PID from the previous command
$ curl http://localhost:9222/json/version --silent # | use jq to get the User-Agent
{
   "Browser": "Chrome/110.0.5481.77",
   "Protocol-Version": "1.3",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
   "V8-Version": "11.0.226.13",
   "WebKit-Version": "537.36 (@65ed616c6e8ee3fe0ad64fe83796c020644d42af)",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:9222/devtools/browser/c2815764-ed1b-4d09-9d7e-db245159c235"
}
$ kill -SIGINT $PID # kill the process or otherwise you'll leave lock files behind.
```

Value from the older way: `{"id":2,"result":{"result":{"type":"string","value":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/110.0.5481.77 Safari/537.36"}}}`

This you would not need to replace "HeadlessChrome" to "Chrome".

Tested with Chrome 112 as well:

```bash
$ /opt/google/chrome/chrome --headless=new --remote-debugging-port=9222 &>/dev/null &
[1] 192
$ PID=$!
$ curl http://localhost:9222/json/version --silent
{
   "Browser": "Chrome/112.0.5615.49",
   "Protocol-Version": "1.3",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
   "V8-Version": "11.2.214.9",
   "WebKit-Version": "537.36 (@bd2a7bcb881c11e8cfe3078709382934e3916914)",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:9222/devtools/browser/3318bf4f-344a-4130-8c0e-1e9ccc85a124"
}
$ kill -SIGINT $PID
```

:)

Comment: Can the socket port be any?

Comment: Yes, any free port. The `--remote-debugging-port` should be same as the one used in `curl`.